# Find position of pyodbc Decimal Data Type in List

Tags: python, list, pyodbc, sqldatatypes

pyodbc returns Decimal data types from sql queries (e.g., Decimal('4117.0000') ).  I want to find the Decimal data types so that I can round them to the hundredths place.

I tried the following:

```
import pyodbc
from decimal import Decimal

#already connected to the sql db.  Fetch the table.  
mssql_table=(list(cursor_mssql.fetchall()))

#Loop through the rows and convert each to a list
for i in range(len(mssql_table)):
    mssql_row=list(mssql_table[i])
```

In one of my data tables a sample **mssql_row** is:

[1, 363, datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 27, 15, 36, 27), 'JONH', 70, 362, Decimal('4117.0000'), 'Bill 27', False, None].

The Decimal data type is in position 6 of the list.

```
    #Find Decimal Data Type position in list
    if(Decimal() in mssql_row):
        decimal_pos = mssql_row.index(Decimal())
```

I expect **decimal_pos** == 6, but the above line returns 8.

In another table a sample row is:
[1, 'United States', 'US', 167, False, 0, True]

Here I expect the if statement to == FALSE, but it returns TRUE and decimal_pos == 4

Instead of finding Decimal, it seems to be finding Boolean data types.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

````
#Find Decimal Data Type position in list
if(Decimal() in mssql_row):
    decimal_pos = mssql_row.index(Decimal())```
````

which fails as described above

Use

```
#For each element in the list
 for i in range(len(mssql_row)):
    #if the element is a Decimal
    if isinstance(mssql_row[i], Decimal):
        #round element to hundredths
        mssql_row[i]=round(mssql_row[i],2)`
```